# Ubuntu ISO with Autoinstall over chroot

Tags: iso, chroot, autoinstall

I'm tasked with migrating 200 physical CentOS 7 servers to a custom Ubuntu 22.04 ISO. This custom ISO comes pre-configured with Autoinstall and seamlessly installs on any server or VM.

However, I'm facing constraints:

- **USB**: I lack direct physical access to the servers.
- **PXE**: Setting up PXE in my current environment is unfeasible.
- **RMM/OOB**: While I can access RMM, deploying any ISO via RMM/OOB isn't an option.

I possess SSH root access to all CentOS 7 servers. My initial thought was to directly install my custom Ubuntu 22.04 ISO onto the CentOS 7 servers, without concern for data loss.
Yet, I'm uncertain about the execution. Could `chroot` be a potential solution? I'd greatly appreciate guidance on this or any alternative methods you might suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?